# I need names for 16 months

Tags: culture

I have 2 moons circling the planet. The smaller moon orbits 16 times per year the larger 12. I am using the current 12 months and zodiac. I have made a second zodiac of 16. However I require 16 new month names as well. Mainly for flavor I realize there is no need for a second time keeping method.

The 2nd Zodiac is Angelus, Pardus, Equus, Formica, Divinos, Ursa, Tritos, Lupus, Draco, Aquilla, Collosaeus, Gulo, Celsior, Amicus, Dryadalis, Pegasus. This is a fantasy world with many intelligent life forms.

So these are the Angel, (Leopard), Unicorn, (Ant), Wizard, (Bear), Triton, (Wolf), Dragon, Griffon, Collossal Creature called a Hexacrus, Wolveryn, Titan, Scion creature of my own design, Pixie's, Pegasus.

The Leopard, Ant, Bear and Wolf are also under different names they are creatures of my own design and name but have a resemblance to those creatures.

I forgot to mention they should be in some kind of logical sense. All Greek or Hindu or something like that.

Comment: We don't generally answer questions that ask for help naming things on WB.  It's opinion based and that's off-topic normally.

Comment: Questions about names *might* be OK, if you will provide constrains that allows objective judgment of answers. If one answer can not be objectively better or worse than others, your question is primarily opinion based and will be closed - that is the fate of most "name this" questions. @StephenG  opinion based =/= off-topic. Questions about names in world are on topic. Reason they are usually closed is unrelated.

Comment: I'm wondering if you understand what the Zodiac is? That has nothing to do with moons or lunar cycles. Might want to google that. Since you're just looking for someone to do the work of creating an assortment of lunar month names, I think a fair price would be base of 40 US dollars per research hour plus $32 for the actual names all nicely systematized.

Comment: You do realise that October-December are just numbers, right? You could go with that, up to 16, and it would make perfect logical sense.

Comment: Why exactly can't you do it yourself? What issues did you run into? I think knowing how months got their names historically, how different cultures measure time and so on is important to know if you are into that kind of world building. However currently at least to me it is unclear what you are asking. Do you just want to know random "Greek" or "Hindu" words? (because so many months have Greek or Hindu names?)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. All good points. I am still learning what the site is generally used for. I did manage it on my own in the last 3-4 hours. For those who are curious and as food for thought.

Comment: Medice: Healer
Spiritus: Air - Courage
Rapax: Predator - "Many"
Natura: Nature - World
Venenatus: Magic - Enchanting
Inperium: Order - Dominion
Hortus: Vineyard - Garden
Amicus: Friend - Kind
Vindex: Protector - Avenger
Caecus:    Invisible - Mysterious
Amplus: Large - "Many"
Hiberno: Winter - Rest
Impetus: Fire - Energy
Martimus: Naval - Changeable
Indomitus: Wild - Fierce
Incedo: Ride -"Many"

Comment: What StephenG said question on cultural trappings like names usually, but not always, fall foul of either being [Too Story-Based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/why-is-my-question-too-story-based-and-how-do-i-get-it-opened).

Answer (score 6):

Month names are usually very logical.  Think numbers, gods, constellations, festivals/feasts/celebrations, etc.  However, you need to remember that the language used to define the month names is *old.*  *Really old.*  But, that's what makes developing names fun.  You need to look back to the earliest civilizations on your world and discover how those words and habits would propagate to the future.

These are, of course, a hair theoretical because looking that far back in the past tends to incure some fogging on the lens.

- Januarius -> Constellation/God Janus -> January
- Februarius -> the Feast of Februa -> February
- Martius -> Planet/God Mars -> March
- Aprilus -> God Aphrodite or "the follower" -> April
- Maius -> God Maia (spring godess) -> May
- Junius -> God Juno -> June
- Julius -> Ceaser Julius (originally Quintillus, "the fifth") -> July
- Augustus -> Caeser Agustus (originally Sextillus, "the sixth") -> August
- Septembre -> September "The Seventh" modern prefix Sept- meaning "7" -> September
- Octobre -> October "The Eighth" modern prefix Octo- meaning "8" -> October
- Novembre -> November "The Ninth" modern prefix Novem- meanin "9" -> November
- Decembre -> December "The Tenth" modern prefix Deca-/Deka- meaning "10" -> December

[Numerical prefixes](https://www.factmonster.com/math/numbers/numerical-prefixes)

The reason July - December, our 7th-12th months, were originally named the fifth-tenth months is that Matius (March) was the first month of the Roman calendar.  Gotta love those Romans.

So, let's begin with 16 months using an ancient alien language...  (I'm teaching you a procedure, not necessarily suggesting actual names):

- 1st - Urkent
- 2nd - Qumora
- 3rd - Hidmner
- 4th - Cheetnu
- 5th - Mymkit
- 6th - Baaphemc
- 7th - Nuore
- 8th - Vyomesh
- 9th - Dinethal
- 10th - Fiurok
- 11th - Rucheira
- 12th - Taoshne
- 13th - Estuuna
- 14th - Poylef
- 15th - Mumonest
- 16th - Shamas

Next, we add some seasonal celebrations/feasts

- 2nd, the feast of Dooma
- 8th, the night of Kasnect
- 15th, the morning of Leabqua

Now we add some local gods...

- 5th, Fas (god of lightening, early spring)
- 9th, Temer (god of fire, full summer)
- 11th, Jan (an imported god, god of victory, due to an early and successful invasion occuring in the 11th month).

Finally, not to let the Romans have all the fun, two wholly narcissistic emporers.

- 1st, M'oash, emporer of the sea
- 12th, M'aendil, emporer of the sea

And finally, we smooth everything out because language tends to shorten and soften.

1. Moas
2. Doma
3. Hidder
4. Sheet
5. Fas
6. Bahem
7. Nuore
8. Kasek
9. Temer
10. Fiuro
11. Jan
12. Mendil
13. Esun
14. Polef
15. Lebu
16. Shama

And you're done.  Have some fun with your backstory!  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Our current 12 months are named for a variety of things, including gods, feasts, and emperors. That being the case, you need to consider what your planet's inhabitants would seek to commemorate. I'm assuming they're colonists, since they have a zodiac and have named their creatures after earth myths, and seem to be familiar with Latin. If that's correct, they're probably naming all the months in one go, in some sort of meeting of government.

If they're democratic, the names will likely be politically motivated. In that case would suggest naming them after historical figures that are popular at the time of colonization, in a similar manner to how "July" came from "Julius." (Caeser)

If they're not democratic, take this opportunity to characterize whichever leader is making this decision. Even if they're not an important character in your world, it will make your world feel more alive. What is that person interested in? What would they like to commemorate? Are they trying to impress another powerful person, such as an emperor who may follow a certain religion or care deeply about his personal lineage? In this case, I would name the months after the emperor's lineage or figures and holidays from his religion, or if the decision-maker is not politically-motivated, after things he is personally interested in - leaders of Earth, planets, stars, etc.

I could give specific name suggestions, but I think the best names are going to come from the ideas above, which would have to be determined by you.